# Reading Image Path in Java

Tags: java, file, path, jlabel

I want to read the full path of an image located in my package to scale it so the image can fit my JLabel, however, everytime I compile my code the following error is produced:

javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)

Code:

```
public void loadImage(){

    BufferedImage img = null;
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("/myPackage/image.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedImage dimg = (BufferedImage) img.getScaledInstance(lblImage.getWidth(), lblImage.getHeight(),
            Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(dimg);

    lblImage.setIcon(imageIcon);
    contentPane.add(lblImage);

}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: try to use the full path to the image

Comment: Where actually is the image?  Since your path starts with "/", it's looking from the root of your drive.

Comment: Also, don't catch the error there, since if there is an IOException, the whole function will fail afterwards.

Comment: Try  
URL urlToImage = this.getClass().getResource("/myPackage/image.jpg"); img = ImageIO.read(urlToImage);

Comment: Ref : https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-an-image-from-file-or-url/